# TypeError: subplots() got multiple values for argument 'sharex'

Tags: matplotlib

[image]

I can't understand the error, please show me the solution.

Comment: [do not include screenshots of your code/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Comment: You confused `plt.subplots` with `plt.subplot`